# connection refused postgres docker

Tags: postgresql, docker, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, datasource

I made a small application with spring-boot, spring jpa data, that connects to a dockerized postgres instace and it works pretty fine, even if I try to connect via 
'psql' to the dockerized postgres instace it works well. The porblem is when I try to dockerize an image's instance of my spring-boot application and I try to link it with the dockerized postegres instance. 
The docker command I use is this

```
docker run -it --link mypgcontainerwithpwd:postgres --name postgresclient1 sprinbootjpa
```

As a I already mentioned the container **mypgcontainerwithpwd** is running and reachable either with a local application either via psql

```
psql -p 5555 postgres postgres
```

in the jar I'm going to execute the **application.properties** file looks like this

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5555/postgres
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
```

During the starting phase an exception is raised up that prints: `connection refused localhost-> 5555`

The dockerfile that builds the instace looks like this

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
VOLUME /tmp
ADD ./SpringJPA-PostgreSQ-0.0.1.jar app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

I'm new to docker and I didn't find anything to fix the issue, I'm running docker on windows 10 with unix containers.

Thanks to all.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your property file you are stating that postgres is running in the same container as your Spring Boot application (localhost) which is not true as it is running in a different container.

Replace you property by this:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://postgres:5555/postgres
```

You could also point to the docker bridge ip which usually is 172.17.0.1.

Comment: Thanks, it worked changing 'localhost' to 172.17.0.1, but not changing it with 'postgres'. Would have docker changed the host file manually to resolve 172.17.0.1 to 'postgres'? 
Anyway thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Change -

`spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5555/postgres`

TO

`spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://postgres:5555/postgres`

Since you started the client container with link `--link mypgcontainerwithpwd:postgres` which means your client will be able to reach your `mypgcontainerwithpwd` container using alias `postgres`. `localhost` means your client container itself & not `mypgcontainerwithpwd`.

Answer (score 1):

This works, but I just want to emphasize Vivek's point that "postgres" comes from the container name and not the userID or the database type.   I am using Docker Compose, so this name comes from my docker-compose.yml file.