# How do I access postgresql within Docker with sqlalchemy?

Tags: postgresql, docker, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to interact with a dockerized PostgreSQL server using SQLAlchemy. Something like:

```
engine = create_engine('postgresql://user:user_password@localhost:5432/database')
df.to_sql('table', engine)
```

Which gives me this error:

> OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) could not connect to server: Connection refused
>       Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
>       TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
>   could not connect to server: Connection refused
>       Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
>       TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

Which suggests the Docker postgresql (which is running) isn't available at that port. I've tried adding `-p 5432:5432` to my `docker-compose exec` without success. Any tips?

Answer (score 11):

## Connecting SQLAlchemy with PostgreSQL on Docker

Hello, guys! Let me try to help you to connect a Flask Web App to a PostgreSQL database, both running on Docker.

#### Please read everything before trying to copy and paste code

First of all you should have installed these python modules:

- SQLAlchemy
- psycopg2

You should install them using **pip**.

psycopg2 is one of the PostgreSQL drivers needed to connect SQLAlchemy to your PostgreSQL database.

---

I'm showing you my *docker-compose.yml* file.

```
version: '3'
services:

  web:
     #YourWebServiceConfiguration
     #YourWebServiceConfiguration
     #YourWebServiceConfiguration

  db_postgres:
    image: postgres:latest
    container_name: postgres_db_container
    ports:
        - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
        - postgres_db_vol:/var/lib/postgresql/data

    environment:
        POSTGRES_USER: yourUserDBName
        POSTGRES_PASSWORD: yourUserDBPassword
        POSTGRES_DB: yourDBName
```

---

Now let's take a look at my python code! This is a *test.py* file.

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session, sessionmaker


conn_url = 'postgresql+psycopg2://yourUserDBName:yourUserDBPassword@yourDBDockerContainerName/yourDBName'

engine = create_engine(conn_url)

db = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine))


query_rows = db.execute("SELECT * FROM anyTableName").fetchall()
for register in query_rows:
    print(f"{register.col_1_name}, {register.col_2_name}, ..., {register.col_n_name}")
    # Note that this Python way of printing is available in Python3 or more!!
```

---

If you want to learn more you can take a look at the following links.

- [SQLAlchemy docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/engines.html#postgresql)

  General database connection url:
      dialect+driver://username:password@host:port/database
- [Simple App with Flask, SQLAlchemy and Docker - Haseeb Majid](https://medium.com/@hmajid2301/implementing-sqlalchemy-with-docker-cb223a8296de)

  If using Docker you need to replace the host value for the docker container name.

Comment: Thanks, very detailed and complete answer.

Answer (score 10):

As your flask app and Postgres images are not in the same docker container you cannot access the database via localhost !!

in your database URL replace *localhost* the name of Postgres Service in docker-compose/

```
engine = create_engine('postgresql://user:user_password@{}:5432/database'.format('service_name_of_postgres'))
```

[kudos to this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48422901/4683950)

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem. After a few tries, it occurs that the problem is in the **connection URL** string given to the *sqlalchemy.create_engine()*

Firstly I had similarly as you:

```
db_URL = f"postgresql://{db_login}:{db_password}@localhost:5432/postgres"
```

Fixed one:

```
db_URL = f"postgresql+psycopg2://{db_login}:{db_password}@db:5432/postgres"
```

A bit dumb approach from my side doing two alterations at once, but I've checked it and looks like the problem was **localhost**. Changing server address to *container_name* stated in the *docker_compose.yml* should fix the problem with the connection.

```
db:
    image: postgres:12.7-alpine
    container_name: db
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and the origin of the problem is that the flask application its not running in the container. So u have two possibles solutions

The first one, initialize a container with flask application togheter with the container postgress, in the same docker compose, or u can add a network drive to your postgress container, like that

```
version: '3.1'
services:
  #CREATING A SERVER, INITIALIZED A CONTAINER
  db:
    image: postgres:16rc1-alpine
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - volumeofpostgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    container_name: postgres_database
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER_FILE: /run/secrets/username-postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD_FILE: /run/secrets/password-postgres
      #POSTGRES_PASSWORD: EXAMPLE
    secrets:
      - username-postgres
      - password-postgres
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    networks:
      - bound
     
#VOLUME ITS NOT A SERVICE ITS A CONFIG    
volumes:
  volumeofpostgres:
    #external: true
    #name: postgres_volume

secrets:
  password-postgres:
    file: password-postgres.secret
  username-postgres:
    file: username-postgres.secret

networks:
  bound:
    driver: bridge
```

than your code with localhost will be working

```
engine = create_engine("postgresql://user:passqword@localhost:5432/postgres")
```

Answer (score 0):

> change your db host name to your yaml service name

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  fast-api:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile 
    container_name: location_micro_service
    ports:
      - "8085:8085"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=admin123
      - POSTGRES_DB=location_service
      - POSTGRES_PORT=5432  # Use the default PostgreSQL port inside the container
      - POSTGRES_HOST_NAME=postgres # Use the service name as the hostname
    command: uvicorn app.main:app --reload --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8085
    volumes:
      - ./app:/app/app
  postgres:
    image: postgres:latest
    container_name: postgres_container
    ports:
      - "5433:5432"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=admin123
      - POSTGRES_DB=location_service
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data  # Persist data to the host machine

volumes:
  postgres_data:
```