# How to connect to an AWS cloud Postgres server from an AWS cloud website in python with psycog2?

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, amazon-web-services, cloud, psycopg2

I am getting the following error when trying to connect to my postgres server when I try the connection from my AWS hosted cloud website.

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) 
connection to server at "myserver.amazonaws.com" (10.192.180.68), 
port 5432 failed: Connection timed out

Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?
```

I have a cloud website that is also hosted in AWS, and my IT has configured firewall rules to allow me to connect the the server from my local machine as well as the cloud. I've been able to make connection from AWS cloud website to AWS cloud database before but the database was an oracle database.

I'm using the following code to test connectivity. It works on my local machine, and I can test the connection, execute SQL this way, and also read and write using the pandas library.

```
def postgres_test():
    import psycopg2
    connection='myserver.amazonaws.com'
    user ='me'
    pwd='my_pwd'

    try:
        conn = psycopg2.connect(database='mydbname',
                            user=user,
                            host=connection,
                            password=pwd,
                            port=5432)
    
        cur = conn.cursor()
    

        conn.close()
    
        return True
    except:
        return False



print(postgres_test())
```

I have tried both this type of connection test as well as a pandas.read_sql() query and both return the same error.

I believe both are RDS instances in docker containers.

The database is on a serverlessV2 Aurora postgreSQL in the uswest2 cluster. The website is in a Amazon EKS cluster in a docker container.

I have also looked at this post but they simply had the wrong host address.
[How do I access postgresql within Docker with sqlalchemy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49325745/how-do-i-access-postgresql-within-docker-with-sqlalchemy?rq=2)

My host address is the amazon service container name, and it works from my local machine.

Comment: Where is the Postgres server running? On the same EC2 instance as the python server? On another EC2 instance? On an RDS instance? Is the python code even running on EC2 or something else like ECS, Lightsail, etc? Just saying "AWS cloud" is too vague. Please specify exactly which AWS services you are using for each component.

Comment: Thank you for this, I was worried I didn't provide enough info. That is handled by my IT team, I need to check with them and get back.

Comment: I'm curious, if you have an IT team that set this up, why are you asking strangers on the Internet to debug your infrastructure for free, instead of asking your IT team?

Comment: This is the first time they have ever set anything like this up. I am the only developer who is able to create web apps in Flask, and my IT is really only willing to set thing up for me at the most basic level.

Comment: The issue is most likely with security groups on the servers, not your code, so the people with access and knowledge of the infrastructure need to be the ones looking at this.

Comment: Best guess there is a firewall rule blocking the 5432 port.

Comment: Well, the FW people said the request isn't even getting to the FW, so maybe it's inside the amazon app.