# psycopg2.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused

Tags: python, postgresql, docker, docker-compose

```
import os
import datetime
from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect, url_for
# from database import DatabaseConnection
# from models import kayıt
from forms import LoginForm
import psycopg2 as p
        
conn=p.connect(dbname='app_db', user='postgres', host='localhost', password='samet', port=5432)
conn.autocommit=True
cur=conn.cursor()
```

conn'and line

```
psycopg2.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused
```

use;
postgresql:9.6.5
python:3

If I only run postgre with the info, but it is not running in python

thank you

Sorry, I should have explained a little more clearly. I'm dealing with a docker. And I have 3 containers, but I am trying to use python container via PostgreSQL. I want to use psycopg2 for this. But I am getting such an error. My login information is correct. I checked.

Comment: Did you check if your `postgresql service` is running fine?
If it's up and running then the problem might be because of wrong `credentials`.

Comment: are you running your python code in the same container as postgres?  if not you'll need to make sure you're bridging ports between the various containers, `docker-compose` makes this easy

Answer (score 3):

Figure out how to solve this problem :

according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48422901/4683950):

> Postgres is not running in the same container as the flask
>   application, that why it cannot be acceded via localhost. we should
>   find the IP address of the docker container with flask and add it, or
>   just add Postgres or volume_name in place of localhost.

So your connection should be like this :

```
conn=p.connect(dbname='app_db', user='postgres', host='volume_name_of_postgres_in_docker_compose', password='samet', port=543
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure all the arguments you are passing to the `psycopg2` `connect` function are correct?

`conn=p.connect(dbname='app_db', user='postgres', host='localhost', password='samet', port=5432)`

The database name, username, host, password, and port all could possibly be incorrect.

Comment: My login information is correct. I checked.My login information is correct. I checked.

Comment: You are definitely overlooking something.